# How to setup mysql remote server digital ocean

Tags: mysql, node.js, server

I have two instances running in digital ocean.

**Instance #1:**

Running NodeJS MySQL grunt for web application.

```
'connection': {
    'host': '`ip-address-for-instance-2`',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '`password`'
},
```

**Instance #2:**

Running phpmyadmin by 'instance-2-ip/phpmyadmin'

I had edit my.cnf bind address with my instance's 2 IP address.

```
bind-address=`ip-address`
```

When I grunt my web application:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 0):

Try this each connector has an optional "address" attribute

tomcat/conf/server.xml.

Specify a bind address for that connector:

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    address="127.0.0.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
  />`
```